# How do I create an Alias for inbuilt parameters such as -Name or -Value in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to type `-nm` or better still `nm` and have Powershell understand it as `-Name` to make entering commands etc easier.

I cannot understand the Microsoft documentation on this - it seems like absolute nonsense:

```
[Alias("UN","Writer","Editor")]
[Parameter()]
public string UserName
{
  get { return userName; }
  set { userName = value; }
}
private string userName;
```

What does that code mean??? What has been aliased? Does that mean that using this snippet I can now use '-UN' instead of '-UserName'? Do I have to re-define each Parameter in order to be able to alias it?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a simple trick.

Open a PowerShell ISE, Go to Edit -> Start Snippets
And choose the `cmdlet (Advanced Function) - Complete`

It would look like this:

[image]

This is a good place to see all you can do with Functions and parameters. What you are looking for is right here. This is how you create an Alias. Don't get mad for throwing more intimidating code at you. Allow me to explain.

Here is a bare minimum of what you will need. That's right, just the `[Alias("p1")` part right before the `param` is defined is all you need.

```
function My-Function
{
    Param
    (
        [Alias("nm")] 
        $Name
    )
    Write-Host "Param suppplied $Name"   
}
```

Comment: What I need is a way to define aliases for built-in parameters, I think I understand how to do it for custom parameters. I need that any parameters I can use in Powershell I can define an alias for. Is this not possible?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to do that unless you edit the code of existing cmdlets. However, If you do `(Get-Command get-process).Parameters.Values` you can see the aliases that are currently set for an existing cmdlet.